# Replace pattern by its length (portable solution for Bash)

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

Is there a way to replace a pattern by its length with Sed/Awk/Perl? I'm looking for small portable commands that can be used in a Bash script.

I have strings that all start with a specific character (let's say `x`), and I want to replace these repetitions of `x` by their length.

So

```
xxxx rest of the line
xxx again
xx again and again
xxxxx you got my point
```

Would become

```
4 rest of the line
3 again
2 again and again
5 you got my point
```

Sed might not be a good candidate. I know Perl has a `e` option that allows to execute code in the substitution string, but I'm not sure how it would be used here: `perl -pe 's/^(x+)/length($1)/e'`?

Comment: Well it seems I found the solution already. The Perl command I wrote is working. Care to add an Awk version :) ?

Comment: Are there always spaces after your leading `x`s? Are there ALWAYS leading `x`s? Do you care about the white space on each line remaining untouched?

Comment: With bash: `while read -r -a array; do array[0]="${#array[0]}"; echo "${array[@]}"; done < file`

Comment: @EdMorton yes, always the space. The character I use though is the "group separator" `\035`.
@Cyrus indeed, simple and pure bash! But I fear it would be a bit too slow on big files :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace first pattern by its length:

```
awk '$1=length($1)' file
```

Output:

```
4 rest of the line
3 again
2 again and again
5 you got my point
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. It's obvious now -_-' Since my lines always start with a repetition of x followed by a space, it works perfectly.

Comment: This works so easy because you use one of awk's default field separators (white space or tab).

Answer (score 2):

It's tagged perl, and there's no solution that's perl, so I'll chip in with one.

You're on the right road with your `/e`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl; 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/^(x+)/length $1/e;
    print;
}
__DATA__
xxxx rest of the line
xxx again
xx again and again
xxxxx you got my point
```

Or as a oneliner:

```
perl -pe 's/^(x+)/length $1/e' file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is `gawk` version, but your perl solution is smarter and better. Capture the leading `xx....` into a variable called `first` using `gensub` function. and later replace the first column with its length.

```
awk '{first=gensub(/(^x+).*/,"\\1","g", $0);$1=length(first)}1' file
4 rest of the line
3 again
2 again and again
5 you got my point
```

Which can be further shortened as:

```
awk '{$1=length(gensub(/(^x+).*/,"\\1","g", $0))}1' file
```